# How do I pass arguments when I import the below .py script as a module?

Tags: python

I know how to execute it via the command line, but looking for input to execute inside another python script. I tried passing the arguments as main(-- score-thr 0.7, --show, vid, config_file, chkpnt_file). Not sure that's how to do it though. Thank you in advance for helping out!

```
import argparse

import cv2
import mmcv

from mmdet.apis import inference_detector, init_detector


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='MMDetection video demo')
    parser.add_argument('video', help='Video file')
    parser.add_argument('config', help='Config file')
    parser.add_argument('checkpoint', help='Checkpoint file')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--device', default='cuda:0', help='Device used for inference')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--score-thr', type=float, default=0.7, help='Bbox score threshold')
    parser.add_argument('--out', type=str, help='Output video file')
    parser.add_argument('--show', action='store_true', help='Show video')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--wait-time',
        type=float,
        default=1,
        help='The interval of show (s), 0 is block')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


def main():
    args = parse_args()
    assert args.out or args.show, \
        ('Please specify at least one operation (save/show the '
         'video) with the argument "--out" or "--show"')

    model = init_detector(args.config, args.checkpoint, device=args.device)

    video_reader = mmcv.VideoReader(args.video)
    video_writer = None
    if args.out:
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
        video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(
            args.out, fourcc, video_reader.fps,
            (video_reader.width, video_reader.height))

    for frame in mmcv.track_iter_progress(video_reader):
        result = inference_detector(model, frame)
        frame = model.show_result(frame, result, score_thr=args.score_thr)
        if args.show:
            cv2.namedWindow('video', 0)
            mmcv.imshow(frame, 'video', args.wait_time)
        if args.out:
            video_writer.write(frame)

    if video_writer:
        video_writer.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You should refactor the script so that it doesn't require the arguments to come from the command line. Separate the command line argument parsing from the functions that do the work. Then you can call those functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

`main()` gets its arguments from `sys.argv` when it uses `argparse`. So you need to fill that in before calling it.

```
sys.argv = ['progname.py', '--score-thr', '0.7', '--show', vid, config_file, chkpnt_file]
main()
```

Comment: Hey Barmar, that was great! Thank you for helping me out!
How do I pass the values into it? For example, I want to pass 0.7 to --score-thr. I tried '--score-thr=0.7' and '--score-thr 0.7'

Comment: I tink `'--score-the=0.7'` should also work.

Comment: Nah, I have tried all of them, didn't work.

Comment: Basically, do it the way you pass arguments on the command line. If they're separate arguments in the shell, make them separate list elements.

Comment: It's supposed to work the way I showed it, I don't know why it's not working for you.

Comment: It's taking as another argument when I have done it your way and throwing an error on it

Comment: Did you include the first element of `sys.argv` before the arguments? I've updated it above to make it clearer.

Comment: On the command line it's just --score-thr 0.7, for some reason it's not working, it's taking the default value from the script, not the value I passed to it.

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` gets the script name when the program is run from the command line. You have to include that placeholder when you do it from the script.

Comment: Oh wow, I have not added that first element! Thank you! That IS working!!
Could you explain what that is for, please?

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining! I did and it's working!! Thank you for following up.